# Use PowerShell to filter Event Logs and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, event-log

I have the following command which gives the information I need but I need to filter it a little further:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select TimeWritten, ReplacementStrings | Export-Csv output.csv
```

This give many entries such as this:

```
09/11/2012 08:09:27                {S-1-5-18, SYSTEM, NT AUTHORITY, 0x3e7...}
```

I want to remove any entry in ReplacementStrings that starts with '{S-1-5' but my attempts to use `Where-Object` and `-notlike` fail to make any difference!

The other problem I have is that without the `Export-Csv output.csv` added it displays on screen fine, but with that it writes to the file like this:

```
"09/11/2012 09:22:05","System.String[]"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select TimeWritten, @{name='ReplacementStrings';Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings -join ';'}} | 
    where {$_.ReplacementStrings -notmatch '^S-1-5'} | Export-Csv output.csv
```